# Check box displaying "on". How to fix?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-lists

So I made this javascript code to add list dynamically. I added a list which has checkbox beside on it in my html file. For unknown reason, there's this "on" that's been added in the list automatically. Please help.

```js
let newList = document.querySelector('input');
let addList = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let ulist = document.querySelector('ul');

newList.addEventListener('change', addNewList);


function addNewList(e) {
  let head1 = document.createElement('h1');
  let list = document.createElement('li');
  let h1Node = document.createTextNode(newList.value);
  list.appendChild(head1);
  ulist.appendChild(list);
  head1.appendChild(h1Node);
  h1Node = document.createTextNode("");

}

addList.onclick = addNewList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Project 1</title>
    <script src = "main.js" async></script>
    <link href = "main.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zhi+Mang+Xing&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">

    <div class = "list">

        <ul>
            <li><h1>Check The Garage</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Practice Basketball</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Take a shower tonight</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Get a girlfriend</h1></li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox" style = "float: left; margin-right: 10px;"><h1>List with checkbox</h1></li>
        </ul>

        <form method = "" action = "">

            <input type = "text" id = "to-doList">

        </form>

        <button type = "submit" id = "addBtn">Add</button>

    </div>

</div>
```

I wanna get rid of that "on" in the list. Please someone explain to me what's going and how can I prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out this line will get rid of it:

```
addList.onclick = addNewList();
```

To test, use:

```
//addList.onclick = addNewList();
```

```js
let newList = document.querySelector('input');
let addList = document.getElementById('addBtn');
let ulist = document.querySelector('ul');

newList.addEventListener('change', addNewList);


function addNewList(e) {
  let head1 = document.createElement('h1');
  let list = document.createElement('li');
  let h1Node = document.createTextNode(newList.value);
  list.appendChild(head1);
  ulist.appendChild(list);
  head1.appendChild(h1Node);
  h1Node = document.createTextNode("");

}

//addList.onclick = addNewList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Project 1</title>
    <script src = "main.js" async></script>
    <link href = "main.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zhi+Mang+Xing&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container">

    <div class = "list">

        <ul>
            <li><h1>Check The Garage</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Practice Basketball</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Take a shower tonight</h1></li>
            <li><h1>Get a girlfriend</h1></li>
            <li><input type = "checkbox" style = "float: left; margin-right: 10px;"><h1>List with checkbox</h1></li>
        </ul>

        <form method = "" action = "">

            <input type = "text" id = "to-doList">

        </form>

        <button type = "submit" id = "addBtn">Add</button>

    </div>

</div>
```